# php request_uri returns image path

Tags: php, session, url-routing

recently I started writing a url routing script in php for urls as such:

http://www.example.com/messages/drafts

To get this effect I am using an .htaccess file that contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.co/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Now templates of the requested pages are loaded through a page class and then on those pages there are switch statements that determine the command to be executed... so:

http://www.example.com/messages/drafts

Would be; load messages.php and execute the drafts command, but you must be logged in to do this. So if your not logged in it redirects you to a login page and sets a session variable that contains the error message and the previous page that was restricted.

For some reason when the url contains more than just /messages or /user_home etc. it sets the session variable to /messages/img/bg.jpg...

The ending is the path to the image on the login page.

I set the session like so `$_SESSION['last_page'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`and then verify it elsewhere.

Does any one have any idea why this would be happening? I'm getting the idea that the problem is in the .htaccess.

When the page is done loading I echo the request uri and it is what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem with a similar setup when using relative links. The problem is that Apache tries to process your background image the same way it does any other request. As a workaround I'm using absolute paths:

```
background-image: url:("http://yoursite.com/images/background.png");
```

instead of:

```
background-image: url:("/images/background.png");
```

I don't know if there's a more elegant solution, but for me this works just fine.

**Clarification:**

I mean to say your redirect is working, but then when the web server is parsing your login page, it treats the reference to your background image the same way it does any url written in the address bar.

Also there's a problem with relatives paths and url rewriting, since when you open www.yoursite.com/something and then have a link with the relative path /image.png, this is interpreted to mean www.yoursite.com/something/image.png

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you, that makes sense. I ended up having to change all of the links as it was because the rewrite was causing issues with paths like "/images/bg.jpg" if the url had more than one parameter as you said.